# Finding the main picture of the Wikipedia page with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia-api

Here's the code I used:

```
import wikipedia as wiki

page = wiki.page("Isaac Newton")
url = page.images[0]
```

It doesn't return the main picture located at the top of the page, but one of the others instead ([this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Bolton-newton.jpg), in this case). How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can try directly with the mediawiki API : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Images

Comment: _It doesn't return the main picture located at the top of the page, but one of the others instead (this one, in this case). How do I fix this?_ As far as I can tell there's nothing to fix here, since there is no indication that the first image in the list should be the main picture.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html),

```
import requests
import json

def get_wiki_main_image(title):
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
    data = {
        'action' :'query',
        'format' : 'json',
        'formatversion' : 2,
        'prop' : 'pageimages|pageterms',
        'piprop' : 'original',
        'titles' : title
    }
    response = requests.get(url, data)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    return json_data['query']['pages'][0]['original']['source'] if len(json_data['query']['pages']) >0 else 'Not found'
get_wiki_main_image('Isaac Newton')
```

Hope you need this output

`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/GodfreyKneller-IsaacNewton-1689.jpg`